# ActivityManager error

Tags: android

I had this error when running the app:

```
[2012-09-05 15:04:51 - ElarabyGroup] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.elarabygroup/.ElarabyGroup }
[2012-09-05 15:04:51 - ElarabyGroup] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Comment: uninstall your application and run it again.

Comment: Also, run a clean build.

Comment: This is not an error, If your application is already running then your console will show this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that Eclipse did not find a change in your project that required it to update the app on the device. Instead, it simply brought the current instance to the front.

Whenever you edit your app and debug it again, eclipse will kill your apps' current process, reinstall the app and then launch your main activity. However, if eclipse thinks that the change you made has no effect, or doesn't know about the change (like when you add a file to the assets folder through a file explorer instead of drag and dropping into eclipse) it will bring your apps current process into the foreground instead of killing it to save resources.

You can tell eclipse there's been a change by going into a java source file, adding a space, deleting the space and compiling. Or you could un install the app on your device, but this will delete its data. There is a way to un install using adb that doesn't remove the data, but I don't remember of the top of my head what it is.

You can also use `Project -> Build Clean` to rebuilt the project from scratch and reinstall on the device.

Answer (score 0):

This says that the activity you want to run is already running on the screen....

"Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"

so the activity already running is brought in front!

Answer (score 0):

your application is running on emulator and you try to again run the same application without any change in code thatwhy you get this . Just press the home button and run your application